# Python check if specific value exists in YAML

Tags: python, yaml

I have a YAML file that I need once in a while to check if a specific section (let's say `test`) exist, and if it does - to check if it contains a value (let's say `value`).

For example, for the following I want to get true:

```
- hello: 1
- bye: 2
- test:
  - a
  - value
```

But for the following false:

```
- hello: 1
- bye: 2
- test:
  - a
```

And false also for this:

```
- hello: 1
- bye: 2
```

The thing is, I want to do it without loading the whole YAML file to memory, because I care only about my `test` section and my `value`.

Is it possible to do it?